# Watching `Console.WriteLine()` messages at client side without attaching the process to Visual Studio

Tags: .net, wpf, debugging

I have a WPF application which is intended to work offline in a 64-GB-RAM/2-CPU-Core devices. I have delivered the output directory to a tester to test the application...

The application is logging messages using different methods: `Debug.WriteLine()`, `Trace.WriteLine()` and `Console.WriteLine()` ... I have seen some tools like [TraceSpy](https://github.com/smourier/TraceSpy) which can show Debug and Trace messages..

I wonder if there is a simple way to watch `Console.WriteLine()` messages at the testing device? or I have to change all my `Console.WriteLine()` to `Trace.WriteLine()`?

Answer (score 0):

When you debug a window application, the console output is redirected to the Visual Studio Output Window. Maybe this work also with other tool like TraceSpy.

Else you can redirect where the console write with [Console.SetOut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setout?view=net-6.0) :

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.SetOut(new TraceWritter());
        Console.WriteLine("Log : Something happened!");
        ...
    }
}
```

You just need implement a custom `TextWriter` and [override only `Write(char)` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter#notes-to-implementers) :

> ## Notes to Implementers
>
> A derived class must minimally implement the Write(Char) method to make a useful instance of TextWriter.

```cs
public class TraceWritter : TextWriter
{
    public override Encoding Encoding => System.Text.Encoding.Default;

    public override void Write(char value)
    {
        Debug.Write(value);
    }
}
```